# SR-IOV: How do I view the communications between a VF and a PF?

Tags: intel, virtualization

I've got a VM using SR-IOV, and I'm trying to understand the communication flows between the VF on the VM and the PF on the underlying host. The VM is using the Intel AVF driver (iavf) and the host is using the ICE driver. I know that the VF and PF are communicating via the AdminQ interface, and I have some logging that shows the Opcodes that are being used in that communication. But I know that we pass more information than this! (For example structures with capabilities information, that sort of thing). I was wondering if there might be a way to snoop on this connection somehow to learn the full contents of the messages that are being sent to each other. Does anyone know of a way to do this?